# PHP PDO SQLITE - error "attempt to write a readonly database"

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, windows-server-2012

I have setup an sqlite database file on my Windows Server 2012 R2 box.

both the database file and the directory it resides in have full control Access (modify, read & execute, read, and write) and I am able to query data from my database with out issue but I am unable to write to the database.

> **exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]:** General error: 8 attempt to write a readonly database' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\newWebsite\dbConnection.php:43 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\newWebsite\dbConnection.php(43): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main}

What do I need to do to ensure that my php scripts will have full read/write access to the database file?

Here is my test statement:

```
    function addUser($uname,$pass,$color) {
        include("dbConnection.php");

        try {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_users (col_uname, col_pass, col_color) VALUES (?,?,?)";
            $results = $db->prepare($sql);
            $results->bindParam(1,$uname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $results->bindParam(2,$pass,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $results->bindParam(3,$color,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $results->execute();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e . " :Unable to add user";
            exit;
        }
    }
```

The **dbConnection.php** file looks like this:

```
    try {
        $db = new PDO("sqlite:".__DIR__."/users.db");
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo '<br>Connection successful.';
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        echo '<br>Connection to the database was unsuccessful. Please check that path to the database file exists.';
        die();
    }
```

Sincerely,
Vaylain

Comment: What do you mean by __full control__? When you right click and go to Security tab do you see group **Everyone** under __Group and user names:__ ? If no tell me and I will try to show you how to grant full content for everyone on a file

Comment: There are several admins including myself and IIS_IUSRS, all baring full check marks and then there is an Users but they are limited to just read/execute access only.  Thank you for the assistance. I do not want to create security risks but at the same time, I do need to make this database available to my php scripts for accessing and updating info.

Comment: OK SAND...thank you for your helpful comment. I was able to get your point and reolve my issue by assigning both the dbConnections.php and the folder it resides in, USERS + write access.  Thank you again for your fine help. I will now need to learn how to assign your post as resolving my original question.

Comment: Great, I'm glad that you figure this out :)

Comment: I think that even only putting write access to users.db file will do the job

Answer (score -1):

For anyone following this post...

I was able to resolve my issue by assigning both the dbConnections.php and the folder it resides in, with the USERS group to include write access.